# Linux SFML - Cannot Open Shared Object File

Tags: c++, linux, sfml, sfml.net, jsfml

Using Linux Mint 18 Cinnamon 64-Bit

I am having issues trying to get SFML to work. I am trying to compile from the command line with g++.

My file is `/home/joe/Desktop/SFML/test/main.cpp`

My SFML Folder is at `/usr/lib/SFML-2.4.1`

If I run `g++ -c main.cpp -I/usr/lib/SFML-2.4.1/include` it compiles fine.
Then I run `g++ main.o -o sfml-app -L/usr/lib/SFML-2.4.1/lib -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-system -lsfml-window -lsfml-audio` This had problems before but after using the -L command it works fine now.

howerver when I run `./sfml-app` I get the error `./sfml-app: error while loading shared libraries: libsfml-graphics.so.2.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Now in the `/usr/lib/SFML-2.4.1/lib` directory libsfml-graphics.so.2.4 is a symlink with the following chain( all files in this directory.

libsfml-graphics.so -> libsfml-graphics.so.2.4 -> libsfml-graphics.so.2.4.1

So can anyone explain to me why the object file can not be found? Thanks

Comment: You can either use `-rpath/usr/lib/SFML-2.4.1/lib` to tell `ld` to include the full path of the library or create a config file in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` pointing to the location of the lib then run `ldconfig`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're running into is the fact that you're telling the linker where to find the library files/information, but when running the program your system won't know where to find the shared libraries belonging to SFML.

The quickest fix is to create a small shell script to run your program which sets the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Something like this should work (untested):

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/SFML-2.4.1/bin ./sfml-app
```

As an alternative, I'd recommend you [compile and install SFML from sources](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.4/compile-with-cmake.php). It's not that complicated. The hardest part is determining all dependencies and get those installed first (preferably using your package manager).

It's also possible to install SFML using `apt-get`, but I'm not 100% sure their version is up to date: `sudo apt-get install libsfml-dev`